# Как создать ссылку в тексте с Arctext.js?

Tags: javascript, html

Не могу поставить ссылку в изогнутом тексте с Arctext.js

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, все работает! 
Файл index.html и jquery.arctext.js находятся в одной папке

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        </head>
        <body>

            <a href="http://google.com"><h1 id="headline">Arctext.js</h1></a>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.arctext.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var $headline = $('#headline').hide();

                google.load('webfont','1');

                google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
                    WebFont.load({
                        google      : {
                            families    : ['Montserrat','Concert One']
                        },
                        fontactive  : function(fontFamily, fontDescription) {
                            init();
                        },
                        fontinactive    : function(fontFamily, fontDescription) {
                            init();
                        }
                    });
                });

                function init()
                {
                    $headline.show().arctext({radius: 400});
                    return false;
                };
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: А как  в изогнутом тексте где несколько слов поставить индивидуальную ссылку на каждое слово?